# How to Parse JSON strings stored as an in DB

Tags: python

From JSON file, the data is created into data base and stored some fields into an array. How to validate these strings that are mapped to this single array.

How can I write a code for this?
For example: 
From this JSON, below strings are stored in DB as an array

From JSON

```
{
    "roadTrip" : [{
    "firstStop" : "Place1",
    "SecondStop" : "Place2",
    "currency" : "DOLLAR"
}]
```

}

To DB:

```
roadTrip:Array
    "firstStop" : "Place1",
    "SecondStop" : "Place2",
    "currency" : "DOLLAR"
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using? What python wrapper?

Comment: Sorry your question has no substance.  Voting to close as "unclear what you are asking"